# Setting Dynamic Attribute to ModelClass

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I have a model, with many attributes(properties). One of them `form_fields` store **JSON** to populate dynamic form fields with validations. Like:

```php
// ./protected/models/FormBuilder.php

/**
 * FormBuilder AR model class with dynamic field building capabilities
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $form_title
 * @property string $form_fields Form fields definitions stored as JSON String
 */
class FormBuilder extends CActiveRecord {

    public function init_form_model() {
        $dynamic_fields = CJSON::decode($this->form_fields);
        foreach($dynamic_fields as $field => $props) {
            // Neither this
            $this->$field = '';
            // nor this working!!!
            $this->setAttribute($field, '');
        }
    }

    /* other methods as it is */
}

// ./protected/controllers/FormBuilderController.php
class FormBuilderController extends CController {
    // ...
    public function actionServing($form_id) {
        $form = FormBuilder::models()->findByPk($form_id);
        $form->init_form_model();
        $this->render('dyn_frm', ['form' => $form]);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Above in method `FormBuilder->init_form_model()` throwing exception. That **Property "FormBuilder.first_name" is not defined.**.

Any solution? How can I proceed further by assigning dynamic property for model class. Yii 1.1 sets attribute if two conditions met, first if class itself has defined property or second AR model's metadata has column named that property being assigned.

I tried to set new property using PHP's ReflectionClass also, but got same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found solution to accomplish this. PHP's Overloading worked well.

So, I opened Yii's CActiveRecord.php source and copied four of it's magic method, and inherited in mine's model class as here:

```php
/**
 * PHP getter magic method.
 * This method is overridden so that AR attributes can be accessed like properties.
 * @param string $name property name
 * @return mixed property value
 * @see getAttribute
 */
public function __get($name) {
    if (isset($this->form_fields[$name])) {
        if (isset($this->form_fields[$name]['value'])) {
            return $this->form_fields[$name]['value'];
        }
        return null;
    }

    return parent::__get($name);
}

/**
 * PHP setter magic method.
 * This method is overridden so that AR attributes can be accessed like properties.
 * @param string $name property name
 * @param mixed $value property value
 * @throws CException
 */
public function __set($name, $value) {
    if (isset($this->form_fields[$name])) {
        $this->form_fields[$name]['value'] = $value;
    } else {
        parent::__set($name, $value);
    }
}

/**
 * Checks if a property value is null.
 * This method overrides the parent implementation by checking
 * if the named attribute is null or not.
 * @param string $name the property name or the event name
 * @return boolean whether the property value is null
 */
public function __isset($name) {
    if (isset($this->form_fields[$name])) {
        return true;
    }
    return parent::__isset($name);
}

/**
 * Sets a component property to be null.
 * This method overrides the parent implementation by clearing
 * the specified attribute value.
 * @param string $name the property name or the event name
 * @throws CException
 */
public function __unset($name) {
    if (isset($this->form_fields[$name])) {
        unset($this->form_fields[$name]);
        return;
    }

    parent::__unset($name);
}
```

Found similar problem with answer here:

[Creating Yii FormModel objects (CFormModel) dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320621/creating-yii-formmodel-objects-cformmodel-dynamically)